# Upload file using MEGAdrop folder (no need to login) link from Python

Tags: python, api, upload

I would like to be able to upload a file in a "MEGAdrop" folder in a Mega account (special folders which everyone can upload, without any kind of mega account nor login, just providing a link) from python.

Can anyone provide a complete snippet to do it?

Thanks